# Why do I not see Create / Copy To links in the Experience Editor?

Tags: jss

I want to be able to add a JSS component to a placeholder in the Experience Editor by creating a new content item, but after I select the rendering I do not see the `Create` or `Copy To` links. I am only able to select pre-existing data items.

I don't think it's a permissions issue: I am using EE as admin so I have full access. I found another question on here that pointed to the renderings not having their `Datasource Template` or `Datasource Location` correctly set, but mine are set properly.

This is in Sitecore 9.1. I have this same JSS app deployed to another environment running Sitecore 9.0 and I see the links there. I haven't been able to get it working since moving to 9.1 but I'm not sure how to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, those links are SXA-specific features. While they might show up when adding JSS components in a Sitecore environment that has both SXA and JSS installed, it's not expected that they'll function as expected.

Comment: Those links should not be visible while adding JSS renderings - even if SXA is installed. I'm pretty sure I was hiding theme, but let me check that again...